# How to throw an exception if CSV item is not in quotes

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am using open csv to parse and read the csv file

Content of `test.csv` -->

```
"COL_1","COL_2",COL_3
```

I want to throw an exception if any of the CSV item is not in double quotes. In my CSV file, `COL_3` is not in double quotes.

However the current `CSVParser` is giving the third record as blank.

The parser -->

```
CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder()
                    .withSeparator(',')
                    .withQuoteChar('"')
                    .withStrictQuotes(true)
                    .withIgnoreQuotations(false)
                    .build();

CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\TEMP\\test.csv")), "UTF-8"))
                    .withCSVParser(parser)
                    .withKeepCarriageReturn(false)
                    .build() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The parser/reader itself is not aware of how many columns there should be and how they have to be filled.

If you want to check the structure of the parsed data, you have to do this manually.

So maybe you want to add something like that:

```
while ((line = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
    if (line.length < 3) {
        throw new ParsingException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think line.length will always be 3. Only the third item will be blank but that is not reducing the array size.

Answer (score 0):

The .withStrictQuotes(true) option on the CSVParser results in characters outside the quote character being ignored, thus the third column in your example is simply ignored.  The only way I have found using OpenCsv (without basically rewriting the parsing, which you could do by supplying a line validator) is to set the quote character to something that will not appear in your data and set .withStrictQuotes(false) like this:

```
    public void test1() {
        CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder()
                .withSeparator(',')
                .withQuoteChar('?')
                .withStrictQuotes(false)
                .withIgnoreQuotations(true)
                .build();

        try {
            File file = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("csv_test.csv").getFile());
            try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file)){
                CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(fileReader)
                            .withCSVParser(parser)
                            .withKeepCarriageReturn(false)
                            .build() ;
                String[] line;
                while((line = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                    if (validate(line)) {
                        processLine(line);
                    } else {
                        throw new Exception("invalid line");
                    }
                }
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private boolean validate(String[] line) {
        boolean isValid = true;
        for (String field: line) {
            if (field.length() > 1 && field.charAt(0) == '"' && field.charAt(field.length() - 1) == '"') {
                isValid &= true;
            } else {
                isValid = false;
                System.out.println("error with field: " + field);
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
    
    private void processLine(String[] line) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. This could be one of the possible solution but my csv could contain data as below  
"COL_1","COL_2","COL,3",COL_4
If I go with the solution above then it will split the 3rd CSV item "COL,3" as "COL and 3" however this is the single CSV item.